# mySQL two date formats in one column

Tags: mysql, str-to-date

I have a table with amongst others the following column:

```
CREATE TABLE `tweets` (
(...)
    `timestamp` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
(...)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

within this column I have two different time formats:

- 2014-08-20 20:17:00
- 18.04.2013 19:57

I'm trying to create a new table with the formatted dates:

```
select
(...)   
case 
    when STR_TO_DATE(t.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') is null
        then STR_TO_DATE(t.timestamp, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i') 
        else STR_TO_DATE(t.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
end as timestamp,
(...)
from tweets;
```

Select code works fine and I learned so far that in mySQL I cannot change the way dates are stored in the database but I can only alter the view on the data.

**However...** Storing dates as text doesn't seem right to me. When I try to save this code by adding:

```
create table `tweets_adj`
select 
(...)    >>>see above
```

I get the error *Incorrect datetime value: '18.04.2013 19:57' for function str_to_date*

How do I set up my database in the correct way?

Thank you SO MUCH.

Comment: are you looking forward to alter your table to change datatype of timestamp column? or inserting data to a new table?

Comment: Hi @UdItSolanki - Thanks for your help! I want to insert the data to a new table (`tweets_adj`)

Comment: in case it is the actual check causing the issue, you might try changing the WHEN condition to something like `SUBSTRING(t.timestamp, 3, 1) = '.'`

Comment: Hi @Uueerdo, thank you. Can you please explain that a little bit more?

Comment: @GreenPirate I mean like `WHEN SUBSTRING(t.timestamp, 3, 1) = '.' THEN STR_TO_DATE...`; having the same expression in the when and else might be causing optimizations in processing to inadvertently/prematurely assume the result of that STR_TO_DATE will be the one used.